# how to post my website content on instagram with share button

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am looking for an API that can post my website's content on instagram with share button; pretty much the same as facebook's sharer.php stuff.
I wonder if such APIs exsits.

FYI, my website will be accessible via normal web browsers like Chrome, Safari, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Instagram, is a photo-sharing platform, the API doesn't allow uploading photos, neither links. Currently, this can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, can't share media on Instagram using the API.

At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Comment: Can you please share the official reference link of this, on which it is mentioned that.